# USB switch keyboard problem on Ubuntu 20 while working on Ubuntu 18

Tags: usb, keyboard, 20.04, mouse

I have 3 computers (Ubuntu 18 + 20, MacOS) and want to use my keyboard and my mouse for all of them so I ordered a "4in/4out USB 3 switch".

Connecting to Ubuntu 18: everything works.
Connecting to Ubuntu 20: only the mouse works, not the keyboard.

It's a split keyboard (Kinesis Freestyle 2). Actually no special hardware beside the fact that it's split, but it doesn't need any additional driver installation on any system I've ever used.

So I checked the system logs:

```bsh
sudo journalctl -f
# and
dmesg -w
```

I also checked diffs of "via switch" and "directly using usb port" but they don't differ except in their port numbers. So in my opinion nothing special.

Then I checked `lsusb` and I found a difference, but I have no idea how to go on.

```
Keyboard (direct port) => working:
Bus 003 Device 053: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard

Keyboard (switch) => not working:
Bus 003 Device 055: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard

Mouse (switch) and keyboard (direct port) => working:
Bus 003 Device 057: ID 06a3:0ccd Saitek PLC KB800 Kinesis Freestyle
Bus 003 Device 056: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard

Mouse (switch) and Keyboard (switch) => not working:
Bus 003 Device 058: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 057: ID 06a3:0ccd Saitek PLC
```

I'd say, Saitek is my mouse, and Alcor is my keyboard. But what should be "Bus 003 Device 057: ID 06a3:0ccd Saitek PLC KB800 Kinesis Freestyle" (mouse + keyboard name combined?) and why is this working while the setup with both connected to the switch having "correct" names doesn't work at all.

`lsusb` on Ubuntu 18 with both connected to switch is the same but it's working:

```
Bus 002 Device 061: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 058: ID 06a3:0ccd Saitek PLC
```

How can I "debug" this?
Thanks for helping.